# IOS/Objective-C: Use NSDate in NSpredicate with Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdate, nspredicate

I am trying to grab items from core data with a date earlier than two minutes ago but my predicate is not returning anything. Of note, when I log the predicate, it employs a cast--and I am not sure why.

Can anyone suggest what might be wrong with the following code?

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSDate *twoMinutesAgo = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60*2]; // Two minutes ago
NSLog(@"twoMinutesAgo%@",twoMinutesAgo);//logs as: 2017-04-17 11:47:57 +0000
NSPredicate *timePred=  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"startdate <= %@", twoMinutesAgo];  
NSLog(@"timePred%@",timePred); //logs as startdate <= CAST(514122477.519686, "NSDate")
```

Comment: Are you sure you have data valid  "startdate" data? Can you get results if you use a different predicate querying a different field?

Comment: If my answer not working then Please check `startdate` attribute in your entity@zztop